# Vector not dereferencable

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio

After having looked at the comments I looked through the code and found an error.

It seems after some tinkering I got faced with this error:

> Debug error: vector iterator is not dereferencable.

I'm 100% certain that it is in the vector inside assingthreads.

**This is the newly added code that spawns the error:**

```
    void historical::writeData(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> in, const string& symbol) {
        std::cout << "Sending data to database connector" << std::endl;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> temp;

        while (!in.empty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                temp.push_back(in.back());
                in.pop_back();
            }
            assignthreads(temp, symbol);
            temp.clear();
        }

    }
    void historical::assignthreads(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>> partVec, const string& symbol) {
        int i = 0;
        std::thread threads[5];
        std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>::iterator it;
        for (it = partVec.end();
             it != partVec.begin();
             it--) {
            std::shared_ptr<database_con> sh_ptr(new database_con);
            threads[i] = std::thread(&database_con::start, sh_ptr, *it, symbol);
            partVec.pop_back();
            i++;
        }
        for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    }
```

Comment: Sorry to be the one to vote to close your first question, but as I'm sure you've seen from the other well received questions you've looked at, http://www.stackoverflow.com is not a debugging service. We don't take in programs and spit out how to fix them. We are here to assist in understanding. As the programmer you find the line that's crashing, then provide the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a crash from that line. (Often times the process of creating said example is enough to solve this bug for you.) But if not post and you'll get help.

Comment: Absolutely fine. Right now I'm reaching out since I'm basically going apeshit because everything I do seems to mount up in some sort of error.

Comment: Start small. From your `main` just running a tiny subset of the code. You may even have to ask other questions to figure out how to create the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't stress about it, it's all learning.

Comment: Just went throug the bitching code and might have found the issue. See the edit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first time through the `for`-loop, `it = partVec.end()`.

By definition you cannot dereference the `end` of a `vector` but you call:

```
threads[i] = std::thread(&database_con::start, sh_ptr, *it, symbol);
```

The `for` loop you intended probably used reverse iterators, [`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin) and [`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend) like this:

```
for(auto it = rbegin(partVec); it != rend(partVec); ++it)
```

---

A couple additional notes:

1. Pass your `vector` by reference: `void assignthreads(std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring>>& partVec, const string& symbol)`
2. You need to validate that `threads` is the same size as `partVec`. So either do: `vector<thread> threads(size(partVec))` or after `threads` is defined do: `assert(size(threads) == size(partVec))`

Comment: This has, by far, been the most helpful.
Would you mind, if you have time, to look at the edit before I accept the answer (of course I'll still accept your answer!)!
Thanks, man! :)

Comment: @geostocker Happy to help. No need to rush to accept my answer though, who knows there may be a better one that comes in later today. But lets do this on the edit, can you just remove it from this question and open a new question? If you do so and you comment with the link here, I'll come try to answer that question. The point being that we want these questions to be helpful to other individuals, and if the questions get so compound that they can't figure out what's being asked they'll give up and move on to search for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

At least one issue with the `for` loop in `assignthreads` is that you attempt to dereference the `end()` of the vector;

```
for (it = partVec.end(); it != partVec.begin(); it--) {
    // ...
    threads[i] = std::thread(&database_con::start, sh_ptr, *it, symbol);
    //                                                    ^^^^
}
```

And on the first iteration of the loop this is undefined; your debugger is just telling you that.

If you want to "reverse" through the loop, use the `reverse_iterator` of the container (available via `rbegin()` and `rend()`)

```
for (it = partVec.rbegin(); it != partVec.rend(); ++it)
```

*Side note* it is generally not advised to modify the container whilst iterating through it (via `partVec.pop_back();`). Since you don't seem to do anything with what is removed from the `vector`, it may just as well be better to iterate over the contents, and then call [`std::vector<>::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) to remove all the contents from the vector after the loop.